# Cart page doesn't show the product image

Tags: magento2, cart, product-images

My checkout cart page doesn't show the product images, I checked the `pub/media/catalog/product/cache` folder and the image via browser inspector, but they are never the same as you can see in the image below.

> I already removed all the third-party modules and my custom theme.

[image: Magento2 checkout cart don't show the product image]

I checked in the database and the route is right, just the generated cache folder is wrong.
I changed this admin option too, but nothing changed.

[image: Magento2 Configurable Product Image]

The original code below gets the wrong image, but when I changed the **cart_page_product_thumbnail** to **category_page_grid** it worked.

```
<?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
```

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it changing the `cart_page_product_thumbnail` to `product_small_image`

```
<?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
```

You can check all the possibilities in this file:

```
vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc/view.xml
```